# how to sort objects by property value array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays like below:

```
const arr = [ 4, 5 ]
const arr2 = [
{
    "id": 1
    "type":[4]
},{
    "id": 2
    "type":[4,1]
},{
    "id": 3
    "type":[4,8,3]
},{
    "id": 4
    "type":[4,5]
}
]
```

how to sort `arr2` in this way, that:

1. such that if the `type` of `arr2` contains all elements in `arr` then those objects are at the very top of the list,
2. when it has at least one element with `arr2` then should be in the next position,
3. and the last ones should be objects that only have one (the only one in `type`) listed in `arr`,

so, the result should be:

```
const arr2 = [
{
    "id": 4
    "type":[4,5]
},{
    "id": 2
    "type":[4,1]
},{
    "id": 3
    "type":[4,8,3]
},{
    "id": 1
    "type":[4]
}
]
```

I try to do this with js` function like below:

```
arr2.sort(e => e.type.includes(arr))
```

but it not working correctly, can omeone tell me how to sort `arr2` in the provided ways? thanks for any help!

Comment: FYI, the `sort` function in Javascript, when called with a callback, expects a callback that takes two parameters and returns either -1, 0, or 1. It should return -1 if the first parameter should come before the second, 0 if the two parameters are equal, and 1 if the the first parameter should come after the second. This isn't a complete answer, but it is part of why your attempted solution does not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [4, 5];
const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: [4],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: [4, 1],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: [4, 8, 3],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: [4, 5],
  },
];

console.log(
  arr2
    .sort((e) => -e.type.length)
    .sort((e) =>
      arr.every((aType) => e.type.includes(aType))
        ? -1
        : e.type.includes(arr)
        ? 0
        : 1,
    ),
);
```

First we sort the array by the length to satisfy condition (3), to have object with one element type at the end.

This pre-sorted array still needs to be sorted according to (1) and (2).

To test for (1) we look at return value of `every`, if it's `true` we return `-1` to have it at the end of the resulting array. If it's not true, we need to test for (2).

The remaining test for (2) is simply done by another call to `includes`, if element is found we return `0`, means it remains at the position of the pre-sorted array. If it's not found we sort it in at the end of the array by returning `1`.

Comment: Thanks, can you paste your code as snippets?

Answer (score 3):

You could count the occurences and sort descending.

```js
const
    getCount = array => types.reduce((s, t) => s + array.includes(t), 0),
    types = [4, 5],
    data = [{ id: 6, type: [] }, { id: 1,  type: [4] }, { id: 2,  type: [4, 1] }, { id: 3,  type: [4, 8, 3] }, { id: 4, type: [4, 5] }, { id: 5, type: [1, 2, 3] }];
  
data.sort(({ type: a}, { type: b }) => {
    const
        countA = getCount(a),
        countB = getCount(b);

    return countB - countA
        || (countA === 1 && a.length === 1) - (countB === 1 && b.length === 1);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but object with `id: 1` must be last one

Answer (score 2):

You can do this elegantly by adding a `weight` function, so that more important elements get less "weight" and literally rise toward the beginning:

```js
const KEYS = [4, 5]

const arr2 = [
    {"id": 1,"type": [4]}, 
    {"id": 2,"type": [4, 1]}, 
    {"id": 3,"type": [4, 8, 3]}, 
    {"id": 4,"type": [4, 5]}
]

function weight(a) {
    let common = a.reduce((cnt, x) => cnt + KEYS.includes(x), 0)

    if (common === KEYS.length)
        return 0

    if (common > 0 && a.length > 1)
        return 1000 + a.length

    if (common > 0)
        return 10_000

    return Infinity
}

arr2.sort(({type: x}, {type: y}) => weight(x) - weight(y))

console.log(arr2)
```